# Amazon S3 SDK for java - configure TLSv1.2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a basic Amazon S3 SDK code snippet which is used to retrieve a list of buckets. The server is configured to only accept TLSv1.2. I am not able to configure my client to send a TLS v1.2 request, debugging shows that client is always sending a TLSv1. I have tried setting the system property, but that does not work either.

-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

```
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(username,password);

        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        final String serviceurl = "https://ip:port";
        s3.setEndpoint(serviceurl);
        S3ClientOptions s3ClientOptions = new S3ClientOptions();
        s3ClientOptions.setPathStyleAccess(false);
        s3.setS3ClientOptions(s3ClientOptions);

        for (Bucket bucket: s3.listBuckets()) {
            System.out.println("Bucket name::" + bucket.getName());
        }
```

What am I missing here? How can I configure the code to always send a TLSv1.2 request? I am using AWS SDK 1.7.25. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

[Version 1.9.4 of the AWS Java SDK made TLSv1.2 the default](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/1974229727246899).

However, it didn't exist in an enum until version 1.9.14 ([code here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/commits/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/http/conn/ssl/TLSProtocol.java)). I'd suggest using that version *as a minimum*.

I believe it's possible to inject this information, but it's a lot of work. I'm probably missing a little bit here:

```
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import com.amazonaws.ApacheHttpClientConfig;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;

SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = ctx.engineGetSocketFactory();

ClientConfiguration client = new ClientConfiguration();
ApacheHttpClientConfig apacheClient = client.getApacheHttpClientConfig();
SSLSocketFactory socketContext = apacheClient.getSslSocketFactory();
apacheClient.setSslSocketFactory(socketFactory);
```

Sources for the injections:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ApacheHttpClientConfig.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html

Comment: I found the root cause for this issue. Amazon S3 SDK will always use TLS if -Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking=true is set. I was using this flag. When I take it off, TLSv1.2 is used.

Answer (score 1):

In Amazon SDK, set the System property to false

```
(SDKGlobalConfiguration.DISABLE_CERT_CHECKING_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "false");
```

If you check, it will internally set com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking to false.

I had the similar issue and referred the same question. The comment made by user3566773 helped me and therefore I thought this must go as an answer.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Real life saver this comment was. Also you can disable or enable via jvm arguments as follows. Disabling is sometimes useful for smoke/int tests. `-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking=true`